# Saving data into hash-map using a jButton

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, hashmap

I'm new to java and need help in saving data into a hash-map via a jButton. I have a GUI which I created in netbeans and has three fields. **Convenor ID, Examiner and Student ID**. The user would simply enter data in each field and click Submit, which should store it into a hash-map. The issue I'm having is I want each record to be unique and have a key starting with G, which is incremented each time a record is submitted. 
E.g **G1 | 1 | KK | thr, tut, tet** : **G2 | 2 | KR | abc, def, ghi** : etc.

```
private void savemode () {
     HashMap<String, Collection<String>> a = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
     int x = Integer.parseInt(counter.getText());
     counter.getText();
String key = "G" + x;
String[] lines = textbox1.getText().split("\n"); 
a.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
a.get(key).add(textbox2.getText());
a.get(key).add(textbox3.getText());
a.get(key).add(Arrays.toString(lines)); 

textbox1.setText("");
textbox2.setText("");
textbox3.setText("");
x++;
counter.setText(Integer.toString(x));
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just posted the code. When the user presses the button the action 'savdemode' occurs. It should save the data into a hashmap and assign a unique key to each record entered beginning with G.

Comment: And what is it that happens?

Comment: It stores the first record with a unique key of G1, but when user adds another record with key of G2, it overwrites the first record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you're saving data, you're recreating your HashMap, and because you only save the current record on the button press, you're never going to retain previous values. A simple solution would be to make your HashMap global, then do a check for existence of the key your user wishes to save/modify before either inserting a new key/value pair or modifying an existing key/value pair.

To make your variable global, do something akin to the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private HashMap<Key, Value> myHashMap = new HashMap<>();

   public void myMethod()
   {
     myHashMap.put(myKeyVariable, myValueVariable);
   }
}
```

Comment: How would do I make the HashMap global. I've been googling it but haven't managed to find an answer.

Comment: I've amended my answer to include an example

Comment: Cheers guys. Managed to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating the HashMap every time you store a record, so the old stored record is erased. Move the HashMap declaration out of the method and create it as a private variable in the class that contains the `saveMode` method.

```
private Map<String, Collection<String>> a = new HashMap<String, Collection<String>>();
```

Then, when the method is called, simply add the new record to the existing map, instead of recreating it every time.